# Should the angular velocity vector change by a sign for an opposite rotation

Tags: angular-momentum, rotational-dynamics, angular-velocity

I have a vector rotating from some rotation matrix:
$$\vec{r_1} = A \vec{r_0},$$
$$A^T \vec{r_1}= \vec{r_0}.$$
To find out how this changes in time:
$$\dot{\vec{r_1}} =\dot{A} \vec{r_0} = \dot{A} A^T \vec{r_1}$$

Then, because
$$A A^T =1$$
We have
$$\dot{A} A^T + A \dot{A^T} =0$$.
$$\dot{A} A^T = -A \dot{A^T} = -(\dot{A} A^T)^T$$
So $\dot{A} A^T$ is an antisymmetric matrix, which means that
$$\dot{\vec{r_1}} = \vec{\omega_1} \times \vec{r_1}$$
For some $\vec{\omega_1}.$ Next, I imagine that this vector is being rotated in the opposite sense,
$$\vec{r_2} = A^T \vec{r_0},$$
$$A \vec{r_2}= \vec{r_0}$$
$$\dot{\vec{r_2}} = \dot{A^T} \vec{r_0} =\dot{A^T} A \vec{r_2} = -A^T \dot{A} \vec{r_2}$$
So (edited for clarity)
$$(\vec{\omega_1} \times {})  = \dot{A}A^T \neq -(-A^T\dot{A}) = -(\vec{\omega_2} \times {}).$$
But if I am rotating in the opposite direction, shouldn't the angular velocity just be the opposite?

Comment: I've cleaned up some comments that seem to have been addressed by edits.  Your notation which equates a matrix operator with the operator "omega times" makes sense but is not something that I've encountered before; I've fiddled with parentheses and kerning to hopefully make it a little clearer to new readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we take as an example
$$A=\begin{bmatrix} 
\cos \omega t & -\sin \omega t & 0 \\
\sin \omega t & \cos \omega t & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{bmatrix},$$
(I will call this the 'simple form') then
$$\dot{A}=\omega \begin{bmatrix} 
-\sin \omega t & -\cos \omega t & 0 \\
\cos \omega t & -\sin \omega t & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{bmatrix},\ A^T= \begin{bmatrix} 
\cos \omega t & \sin \omega t & 0 \\
-\sin \omega t & \cos\omega t & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{bmatrix};$$
$$\dot{A} A^T = \omega \begin{bmatrix}
0 & -1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}, \  A^T \dot{A} = \omega \begin{bmatrix}
0 & -1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}.$$
So in this case they *do* commute and we have the expected result: $$\vec{\omega_1} = \omega \hat{k}$$
$$ \vec{\omega_2} = - \omega \hat{k}.$$
But I was confused, because when we parametrize by the Euler angles, they don't commute. Take
$$A = BCD = \begin{bmatrix} \cos \psi & -\sin \psi & 0 \\ 
\sin \psi & \cos \psi & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \cos \theta & -\sin \theta  \\ 
0 & \sin \theta & \cos \theta \\
 \end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix} \cos \phi & -\sin \phi & 0 \\ 
\sin \phi & \cos \phi & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}  $$
$$A = \begin{bmatrix} \cos \psi \cos \phi - \cos \theta \sin \phi \sin \psi & -\sin \psi \cos \phi - \cos \theta \sin \phi \cos \psi & \sin \theta \sin \phi \\
\cos \psi \sin \phi + \cos \theta \cos \phi \sin \psi & -\sin \psi \sin \phi + \cos \theta \cos\phi \cos \psi & - \sin \theta \cos \phi \\
\sin \theta \sin \psi  & \sin \theta \cos \psi  & \cos \theta \\
\end{bmatrix}.$$
I won't multiply this out, but the end result simplifies (you can use Mathematica), and you'll see that $\dot{A} A^T \neq A^T \dot{A}.$ You can also see the different results of this on page 174 of Goldstein, and page 181. (They used a passive transformation for $A$ though, whereas I used an active transformation).

So I was left wondering: if the matrix $A$ represented with Euler angles is also a rotation about an arbitrary axis, then I should be able to put it into the simple form described in the first part of this post for some basis. But in *that* basis they do commute.

The flaw with this reasoning is that $\dot{A}$ in the simple form assumes that the axis of rotation is constant. But when we parametrize by Euler angles, changing $\psi, \dot{\psi}, ...$ etc. *also* changes the axis of rotation.

So, we shouldn't expect the angular velocity vector to change by a sign, because it was not ever constant in the first place.